# C/C++ struct with bits fields packing in buffer

Tags: c++, c, sockets, struct, bit

I have defined my struct with bit fields.

```
typedef struct{
   unsigned char primero;
   unsigned int bit1: 1;
   unsigned int bit2: 1;
   unsigned char segundo;
   unsigned char array[4];
   unsigned int offset: 6;
} date;
```

I want to send this data by a socket in this specific orer of bits.

```
char auxsendbuf[BUF_SIZ];
memset(sendbuf, 0, BUF_SIZ);
date *st = (date *) auxsendbuf;

st->primero = 0x01;
st->bit1 = 1;
st->bit2 = 1;
st->segundo = 0x03;
st->array[0] = 0x04;
st->array[1] = 0x05;
st->array[2] = 0x06;
st->array[3] = 0x07;
```

My problem is that bit1 and bit2 are filled with 0s to complete a extra byte that i don't want to send. This is the result...

```
01 03 03 04 05 06 07 00 50
```

How can I force the order of bites? I can use C++ if it would necessary.

Comment: Identity-encoding stuff you are sending over the wire (with the bit fields!) is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 3):

You need to group the fields so that the bitfields are together:

```
typedef struct{
   unsigned char primero;
   unsigned int bit1: 1;
   unsigned int bit2: 1;
   unsigned int offset: 6;
   unsigned char segundo;
   unsigned char array[4];
} date;
```

EDIT:

If  you want all the bits to be packed the original order without padding, you need to make bit fields out of everything else in between:

```
typedef struct{
   unsigned char primero;
   unsigned int bit1: 1;
   unsigned int bit2: 1;
   unsigned char segundo: 8;
   unsigned char array0: 8;
   unsigned char array1: 8;
   unsigned char array2: 8;
   unsigned char array3: 8;
   unsigned int offset: 6;
} date;
```

Note here that you can't have an array inside of a bitfield.

Why exactly do you need the bits in this order?  Because any solution that uses it will be very convoluted.

Comment: That's just that I dont want to do. I obtain the same result obiously. I want to merge the bits bit1 and bit2 with 6 bits of field segundo. I want to put the offset at last part of my packet.

Comment: @XabiE To accomplish that you're going to have to serialize your packet at the bit level with bit shifting and masking.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler can do weird things with your bit-fields. It's basically a "best-effort" approach, there is no standard way to influence it. In my experience, the best thing is to *not* use bit-fields for the purpose of "message-mapping". Declare the byte(s) you want to send and then do the bit-operations (setting and getting the bits you need) yourself.

Actually, since there could be issues with structure members' size, alignment and padding, and byte-ordering (for multi-byte data) to be perfectly safe, don't use structures either. Pack and unpack the message to an array of bytes yourself. Only in some application-specific optimizations and with some checks (using `sizeof` and `ofsetoff` tricks) should you use structures for message-mapping.